# how can i create Ext.net wrapper class for ext.js custom control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs, ext.net

I have made some changes to the existing ext.js calendar control. I have removed the month view and day view from it. I have now only the week view in the ext.js calendar. I have changed week view such that each day now looks like a day for a person. the five days in the week now looks like the selected day of 5 people.

It works without much issues. now I want (told) to write a ext.net wrapper for this modified calendar tool.

I have experience in c#.net and mvc3 but i don't know much knwoledge about ext.net.

Can someone give me direction to write a wrapper class for this custom control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide [how to extend Ext.NET controls](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18103-CLOSED-Adding-events-to-custom-control&p=78126&viewfull=1#post78126).